# Convert image from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, wgs84, gdal-translate, web-mercator

I'm new to GDAL and map projections, I need to convert equirectangular (EPSG:4326?) projection to "pseudo Mercator" (EPSG:3857?) projection used by 90% web-based maps (which is simple this 0/0/0 file of any OSM tileserver: https://tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/0.png). I have the following EPSG:4326 example:

[image: ESPG:4326 wold map projection]

I run the following commands:

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr -180 85.05 180 -85.05 -a_srs EPSG:4326 4326.png 4326.tiff
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 4326.tiff 3857.png
```

But the output (to the left) is obviously not the same as the EPSG:3857 example (to the right):

[image: My result vs EPSG:3857]

I feel like I need some offset parameter from the top of the source, or I set wrong `a_ullr` parameter, or I chose wrong projections. In other words: I need to make a googlemap-like image from the given source. How can I do it in a correct way?

Comment: I would first look at making sure your tiff is in 4326. Going from a non-spatial format (png) to a spatial format (tif)

Comment: How do you know the ullr coordinates of your source image? Where does "EPSG:3857 example (to the right)" come?

Comment: @Nate I thought it's made with gdal_translate?

Comment: @user30184 I'm not sure about ullr parameter, I've looked different sources, spatialreference.org says it should be -180 90 180 -90 but then I get a very strange vertical picture 133x1605px. I've played with it a bit but it seems there's no way to make less space above the Greenland, you can only shift the map center to the north/south. The example of EPSG:3857 "web mercator" comes directly from OSM map, it's the same as many results you can google with this keyword (wikipedia for example).

Comment: The ullr parameters must match with the area that your original image presents. Do you have any metadata about it?

Comment: @user30184 no I don't have, I just googled and compared different pictures and searched which projections they could be. But I'm quite sure about source projection: it's a definitely equirectangular projection, some call it "plate carrée" or "pseudo plate carrée", but I'm new to this so it's quite overwhelming for now to understand all that concepts (coordinate systems and projections). I thought it should be quite a simple task: we have 2 popular projections, and for now I just need to convert from one to another. The mistake can be anywhere: I could pick up wrong projection, wrong ullr etc.

Comment: @user30184 as to destination projection - it's simple this 0/0/0 file of any OSM tileserver, for example: https://tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/0.png and many sources describe it as EPSG:3857 "pseudo Mercator" projection which in use by 90% web-based maps.

Comment: I mean this image in your question https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib0e7.png. You must know the right corner coordinates if you want to use them as ullr. If you do not know the corner coordinates you cannot just guess them.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a solution: so the `-a_ullr` bounds for the source projection will be `-180 90 180 -90`, and then I've learned that EPSG:3857 has an extent in coordinates which is `-20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34`. So the commands will be:

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 -a_srs EPSG:4326 4326.png 4326.tiff
gdalwarp -te -20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34 -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 4326.tiff 3857.png
```

And now it looks much better:

[image]